# Constant time source

Tags: google-docs

I have an interesting one for you all.. is it possible to paste a date and time from an external constant time source ?

The reasoning behind this is as follows.

We have a few people accessing the same spreadsheet here on gdocs who are in different timezones.

One of the formulas used is "now()" and this is also the problem. If Paul opens the doc in Seattle he get his local time inserted as per his PC time (lets say 10AM)  .. now Mary opens the same document literally 1sec later, but she is in London and now it displays 01PM (time may not be right, I'm not on top of all the zones but the point should be clear), Abdul opens it it at the same time and is in India and his displays 04PM

All these people opened the document at around the same time but everybody gets their local time inserted.

Is there a formula that will insert a sever time or a utc time or something.. something that we can use that will display the same time to everybody ? a google time .. any time source that is constant and does not change ?

thank you.

Comment: May be I missed something, but the Spreadsheet's `now()` function returns time in the Spreadsheets time zone and not in users local time zone.

Comment: when you say "All these people opened the document at around the same time but everybody gets their local time inserted." do you mean that a time stamps is added to the sheet somehow ? Are you using a script to do so ? The spreadsheet itself has its own timezone settings (as megabyte1024 said), the user location doesn't have any importance so unless I missed something I'd say that I don't see how you are getting this situation... could you explain ?

Comment: no, it rarely happens that all open it at the same time, it is just the scenario, it does however happen that the UK & India have it open and then the confusion is big as we calculate shipment times and these will vary due to the =now() formula.

The staff is aware of this and work the time back to GMT, but it would be so nice if we could get a timesource, or timestamp that is not from the local machines and base our formulas on that.

Comment: easiest example I can think of is create a sheet, use the formula and see the time, now change your computer time a few hours forward and open the Spreadsheet again. now the formula will reflect the new time.